# How to get the popup .circle fixed?

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```css
.container {
  background: #000;
  width:100%;
  min-height:800px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.popup {
  background:#fff;
  width:50%;
  height:70%;
  position:absolute; 
  overflow:auto;
  border: 4px solid #678;
  margin: auto;
  display:block;
  top: 0;  right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index:100;
  border-radius:10px;
}

.popup h1 {
  display:block;
  font-size:24px;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  top:20px;
}

.popup p {
  width:60%;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-bottom:40px;
}

.popup img {
  
  widht:50%;
  height:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  top:50;
}

.circle {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:600;
  right:450px;
  top:100px;
  display:block;
}

.circle button{
  display:block;
  color:#000;
    border-radius:50%;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:relative;
  background-color:#fff;
  border: 4px solid #678;
}

.circle button:hover {
  border: 5px solid #000; 
}

.show button{
  width:60%;
  height:40px;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="popup">
      <h1>10 euro actie</h1>
    <img src="http://swbolt.gobizkorea.com/att/cat/a056078117086/tp_html/img/a056078117086_cat_958686_large_img1_2.jpg"></img>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, toen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen overleefd maar is ook, vrijwel onveranderd, overgenomen in elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 populair geworden met de introductie van Letraset vellen met Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.
</p>
    <div class="show">
      <button>Bekijk de actie</button>
    </div> 
    
  </div>
        <div class="closing">
          <div class="circle">
            <button>X</button>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is that the circle is staying fixed in the corner. In the desktop is stays there. But when I minimalize the screen, it's changing the position. How do I fix this?

Comment: You will need to place `div.closing` inside `.container`, move `width` and `height` from `.popup` to `.container` and make other necessary style changes according.

Comment: any reason you need .popup as absolute??

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to move `.closing` inside `.popup`, remove `overflow: auto` from `.popup` so that `.circle` is visible after fixing its position.

Made other changes to your css to meet your requirement:

```css
.container {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 800px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.popup {
  background: #fff;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 4px solid #678;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.popup h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 20px;
}
.popup p {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.popup img {
  widht: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  top: 50;
}
.closing {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: -25px;
  left: -25px;
}
.circle {
  z-index: 600;
}
.circle button {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 4px solid #678;
}
.circle button:hover {
  border: 5px solid #000;
}
.show button {
  width: 60%;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="popup">
    <h1>10 euro actie</h1>
    <img src="http://swbolt.gobizkorea.com/att/cat/a056078117086/tp_html/img/a056078117086_cat_958686_large_img1_2.jpg"></img>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, toen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus
      te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen overleefd maar is ook, vrijwel onveranderd, overgenomen in elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 populair geworden met de introductie van Letraset vellen met Lorem Ipsum passages en meer
      recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.
    </p>
    <div class="show">
      <button>Bekijk de actie</button>
    </div>
    <div class="closing">
      <div class="circle">
        <button>X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```